# jQuery validate plugin and jQuery Mobile - adding error class to fieldset/.ui-controlgroup-controls

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-validate

I'm trying to validate a group of form inputs -- in this case a group of radio buttons, on a form built with jQuery Mobile. I'd like to add a class to the whole fieldset (or, rather, the .ui-controlgroup-controls div) if no button in the group has been selected, so that I can re-style the border around the group. The code below will accomplish that, *but* once the group is valid, does not un-do the change. Is there a way for me to trigger the addition of the class if there's an error, and then remove it once the field is valid? Thanks!

(I'm using jQuery Mobile 1.1.0, jQuery 1.7.2, and Validate 1.9.0)

```
$('#contact').validate({
    errorPlacement: function(error, element)
    {
        if( element.closest('#employee-group').length ) {
        // special error handling
        $('#employee-group .ui-controlgroup-controls').toggleClass('grouperror');
    } else {
        // generic handling
        error.insertAfter(element);
    }
    }
});
```